# How to make the bottomsheet swipe down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, bottom-sheet

The bottom sheet doesn't swipe down

Hello I'm new to react native and I have implemented the bottom sheet from the react "@gorhom/bottom-sheet" package , bottom sheet appears but the issue is once it is opened I cant swipe it back down. Can you help me to solve this. Thank you in advance.Following is the part of the code that I tried

```
<BottomSheet
 ref={bottomSheetRef}
 index={-1}
 snapPoints={snapPoints}
 enablePanDownToClose={true}
 backgroundStyle={{
 borderTopRightRadius: 60,
 borderTopLeftRadius: 60,
 }}
 onClose={handleBottomSheetClose}
 >
 <BottomSheetView>
  {/* my Bottom Sheet Content */}
  <View style={styles.bottomSheetContent}>
   <Text>Filter Options</Text>
  {/* my filter options go here */}
  </View>
   </BottomSheetView>
   </BottomSheet>
```

Comment: Hello, can we have the content of the `handleBottomSheetClose` function please?

Comment: const [isBottomSheetVisible, setIsBottomSheetVisible] = useState(false);             
  const handleBottomSheetClose = () => {
    setIsBottomSheetVisible(false);
  };                                                                                                                              
   const handleFilterClick = () => {
    setIsBottomSheetVisible(true);
    bottomSheetRef.current.expand();
  };

Comment: You might actually want to look at enablePanDownToClose. The prop is at this link: https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/props/#enablepandowntoclose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't use `onClose` on the `<BottomSheet />` component. This props doesn't seem exist on this component.

This is an example [BottomSheetView](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/components/bottomsheetview) from the documentation:

```js
import React, { useCallback, useRef, useMemo } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import BottomSheet, { BottomSheetView } from "@gorhom/bottom-sheet";

const App = () => {
  // hooks
  const sheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);

  // variables
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ["25%", "50%", "90%"], []);

  // callbacks
  const handleSheetChange = useCallback((index) => {
    console.log("handleSheetChange", index);
  }, []);
  const handleSnapPress = useCallback((index) => {
    sheetRef.current?.snapToIndex(index);
  }, []);
  const handleClosePress = useCallback(() => {
    sheetRef.current?.close();
  }, []);

  // render
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Snap To 90%" onPress={() => handleSnapPress(2)} />
      <Button title="Snap To 50%" onPress={() => handleSnapPress(1)} />
      <Button title="Snap To 25%" onPress={() => handleSnapPress(0)} />
      <Button title="Close" onPress={() => handleClosePress()} />
      <BottomSheet
        ref={sheetRef}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        onChange={handleSheetChange}
      >
        <BottomSheetView>
          <Text>Awesome </Text>
        </BottomSheetView>
      </BottomSheet>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 200,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Like you can see, to close the sheetview, there is a `<Button onPress={() => handleClosePress()} />` component.

Anyway, in your case, I think your code should be like this below. You have to use the `<GestureHandlerRootView />`. You can wrap your entire `<App />` or just the `<BottomSheet />`. You can see this issues on [enablePanDownToClose not working on iOS and Android](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet/issues/775).

Actually there is a warning from the documentation [Installation](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/#installation)

> **Note**:
> React Native Gesture Handler needs extra steps to finalize its installation, please follow their installation instructions. Please make sure to wrap your App with GestureHandlerRootView when you've upgraded to React Native Gesture Handler ^2.
> React Native Reanimated v2 needs extra steps to finalize its installation, please follow their installation instructions.

```js
return (
<GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex: 1}}>
 <BottomSheet
   ref={bottomSheetRef}
   index={-1}
   snapPoints={snapPoints}
   enablePanDownToClose={true}
   backgroundStyle={{
     borderTopRightRadius: 60,
     borderTopLeftRadius: 60,
   }}
   onClose={handleBottomSheetClose}
  >
   <BottomSheetView>
     {/* my Bottom Sheet Content */}
     <View style={styles.bottomSheetContent}>
       <Text>Filter Options</Text>
       {/* my filter options go here */}
     </View>
    </BottomSheetView>
  </BottomSheet>
<GestureHandlerRootView />
)
```

Comment: Thankyou so much it worked when i wrapped my app with GestureHandlerRootView but I can see a white margin at the bottom of the page is it because the gesturehandler?

Comment: when I removed the flex style it worked . Thank you so much for your help ;)

Comment: You're welcome :) if your problem is fixed, don't hesitate to mark the answer as `accepted` ;) thanks